# Query , joining, SQL server example (Concert) with a couple of related tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I dont know who to return what I wrote before, apologise. vowejin firnefk rneqkln qrecjinrelqkjnr klwencirowejncienfvenciernicnreinc ikrenicernircniwncikwnkwjnkcjwnkjnckjncwkjnwckjnweknckejnckwjnckjnwekcjnwekjnckwjenckjwenkcjnwekjnckwenckwjenklwneocnwocnowencoejnkjwencojnwekojcnwekjcnkwejnckejcnkwejnckjwenkcjnwkjcnwkn:)

Answer (score 1):

This should return expected result

```
;with Cte1 AS (
select C.CID, P.Name AS PerformerName, H.Name AS HallName, H.Capacity, H.HID
from @Performer P 
    inner join @Concert C on C.PID = P.PID
    inner join @Hall H on H.HID = C.HID
)
, Cte2 AS (
select C.CID, H.HID, COUNT(*) SellCount
from @Concert C 
    inner join @Hall H on H.HID = C.HID
    inner join @Tickets T on T.CID = C.CID
group by C.CID, H.HID
)
select Cte1.CID, Cte1.PerformerName, Cte1.HallName, Cte2.SellCount
from Cte1 inner join Cte2 on Cte2.CID = Cte1.CID AND Cte2.HID = Cte1.HID
where Cte1.Capacity = Cte2.SellCount
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    PID, NAME, AGE
FROM (
    SELECT
        p.*, h.HID
    FROM Performer p
    INNER JOIN Concert c
        ON c.PID = p.PID
    INNER JOIN Hall h
        ON h.HID = c.HID
    INNER JOIN Tickets t
        ON t.CID = c.CID
    GROUP BY p.PID, p.NAME, p.AGE, h.HID, h.CAPACITY
    HAVING COUNT(t.TID) = h.CAPACITY
) t
GROUP BY PID, NAME, AGE
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Is this TOP function universal to all SQL platforms, what does it mean?